# Combinatorics problem about a choir

Tags: combinatorics

The choir consists of 10 members. How many ways there are to choose 6 participants during three days of the festival , so that each day we have a different choir?

Comment: Does everybody have to sing at least once? Can people sing three times?

Comment: I have the same question, to be honest

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that the problem were choose one of $n$ possible options, during three different days, such that no option is repeated in any of the days.

The number of ways to do this would be $n\times (n-1)\times (n-2)$.

In our case, $n=\binom{10}{6}$, and then the total number of ways to choose six participants during three days such that each day we have a different choir is $$\binom{10}{6}\times \left(\binom{10}{6}-1\right)\times \left(\binom{10}{6}-2\right),$$

unless there is some explicit restriction in the problem that I am not understanding.